# Random seed in research papers

Tags: random, metrics, seed

To present results in research papers, a random seed is typically used for repeatability. However, it we know that the choice of the random seed can significantly impact the obtained results. This makes me wonder what researches do to report their results metrics.

Do they select the seed that produces the highest or lowest metrics, or report the average.

Comment: [se] is by now a very large collection of Q/A sites. [so] is and always has been about programming topics. At the current time your question is probably better suited for other sites such as [academia.se]. Please read their help pages about what is on topic though. I'd include an example / specific case make your question easier to answer, as the answer may of course differ for each instance.

Comment: If the choice of random seed "significantly" affects the results, I'd say the researchers haven't done enough sampling to justify their conclusions.